# How can I make gdb save the command history?

Tags: debugging, gdb

How can I set up `gdb` so that it saves the command history? When starting a new `gdb` session I'd like to use the arrow up keys to access the commands of the previous sessions.

Comment: Note: The `.gdbinit` file has to be write-protected by others than you on linux.

Comment: @urzeit - I think that's a lost cause on distros like Ubuntu. They allow anyone into anyone else's home directory by default.

Comment: @jww The `.gdbinit` file is not processed if the permissions are not set up correctly, no matter what is the default or what other limitations on home-directories are used by the system.

Comment: @urzeit If you create a `.gdbinit` file and that is not the case, it means your `umask` isn't set to a sane value like `022`.  Then  in a multi-user system, you have bigger problems than just your `.gdbinit` file.

Answer (score 373):

Short answer:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/gdb
echo 'set history save on' >> ~/.config/gdb/gdbinit
```

---

Long answer:

Command history is covered in the [GDB manual, 22.3 Command History](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-History.html). Create a file `$HOME/.config/gdb/gdbinit`, and add the following line:

```
set history save on
```

You can set the number of past commands saved with the following. The command is described as *"Set the number of commands which gdb keeps in its history list. This defaults to the value of the environment variable GDBHISTSIZE, or to 256 if this variable is not set. Non-numeric values of GDBHISTSIZE are ignored. If size is unlimited or if GDBHISTSIZE is either a negative number or the empty string, then the number of commands gdb keeps in the history list is unlimited"*.

```
set history size <size>
```

A related command is `set history remove-duplicates <count>`. The command is described as *"Control the removal of duplicate history entries in the command history list. If count is non-zero, gdb will look back at the last count history entries and remove the first entry that is a duplicate of the current entry being added to the command history list. If count is unlimited then this lookbehind is unbounded. If count is 0, then removal of duplicate history entries is disabled"*.

```
set history remove-duplicates <count>
```

By default, gdb saves the history into the file ./.gdb_history [in the current directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-History.html). If you want your command history not to depend on the directory you are in, also include:

```
set history filename ~/.gdb_history
```

Comment: Just found this out for myself and thought I'd share it on SO.

Comment: For next time, it's perfectly legitimate to create such self-answered questions as non-community-wiki. :)

Comment: @Frank How about if I type `n` then I arrow up key, I get all previous commands that start with `n`.

Comment: On GDB 8.0.1 this appears to work without the special file permissions.

Comment: @Ryan1729 Permissions of 0600 (octal) are not mandatory. 0644 (read/write to the owner, read to everybody else) will also work. Many linux variants set umask to 0022, which means, that files are created with 0644, so they are fine for the purpose of `.gdbinit` then. But Debian/Ubuntu create a private group for each user and sets umask to 0002, so that files by default are also writeable to anybody in that private group. This eases account sharing (just add your friend to your private group to give them full access), but violates gdbs security requirement for `.gdbinit`.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and this setup only worked for me when I created the init file in `$HOME/.gdbinit`. This is my version: "GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2"

Comment: Needed to use `$HOME/.gdbinit` on Fedora 35 and RHEL 8

Answer (score 9):

If you're still having trouble, make sure your HISTSIZE environment variable is a suitably high number. Mine was empty, causing gdb's "history size" setting to default to 0.

Added

```
export HISTSIZE=100000000
```

to my ~/.bashrc and everything is swell

You can check your gdb history settings by doing (inside gdb) "show history":

```
gdb$ show history
expansion:  History expansion on command input is off.
filename:  The filename in which to record the command history is "/home/xiao/.gdb_history".
save:  Saving of the history record on exit is on.
size:  The size of the command history is 100000000.
```

From the [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-History.html):

> **set history size *size***
>   **set history size unlimited**
>   Set the number of commands which GDB keeps in its history list. This defaults to the value of the environment variable HISTSIZE, or to 256 if this variable is not set. If size is unlimited, the number of commands GDB keeps in the history list is unlimited.

Comment: I had the same problem. Despite putting `set history size 100` in the .gdbinit file, the HISTSIZE environment variable was still causing the history size to be set to zero.
The problem is that gdb doesn't understand that [HISTSIZE can be set to unlimited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history)

Comment: The HISTSIZE bug in gdb has been [fixed as of June 2015](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16999), not that this change is likely to be present on your system yet. In the meanwhile, if `HISTSIZE` is set it must be > 0, or gdb will disable history.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 set `~/.bashrc` with

```
export GDBHISTSIZE=10000
```

then run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```