# Unlimited Bash History

Tags: bash, unix

I want my `.bash_history` file to be unlimited. e.g. So I can always go back and see how I built/configured something, or what that nifty command was, or how some command broke something weeks ago. How do I change this setting?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/137438/how-to-unlimited-bash-shell-history

Comment: Bash is a programming language and this is not about programming?

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Set `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` in .bashrc to an empty string:

```
HISTSIZE= 
HISTFILESIZE=
```

In [bash 4.3 and later](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) you can also use `HISTSIZE=-1 HISTFILESIZE=-1`:

```
n.  Setting HISTSIZE to a value less than zero causes the history list to be
    unlimited (setting it 0 zero disables the history list).

o.  Setting HISTFILESIZE to a value less than zero causes the history file size
    to be unlimited (setting it to 0 causes the history file to be truncated
    to zero size).
```

`bash --version` to check your bash version.

Comment: Could I put this setting globally in global bashrc so that it overrides settings for all users ?

Comment: (export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a') can flush commands to bash history immediately.

Comment: Setting ``HISTSIZE= HISTFILESIZE=`` results in completely disabling the bash history, at least for me.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig setting `HISTSIZE=-1 HISTFILESIZE=-1` disabled my history, while `HISTSIZE= HISTFILESIZE=` did the trick. CentOS 7 here.

Comment: Same for me: -1 disables history on centOS

Comment: @PhilippLudwig
I think rather than `HISTSIZE= HISTFILESIZE=` you should
`export HISTSIZE=`
`export HISTFILESIZE=`

Comment: @Seether The answer clearly states "In bash 4.3 and later...". CentOS 7 has bash 4.2.x.

Comment: changed both settings and that did not work for me

Comment: @Seether is villapx correct?  Please put accurate information on the internet so everyone knows what's really going on

Comment: bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.0(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

export HISTSIZE=-1 && export HISTFILESIZE=-1 

disabled my history

 lsb_release -d
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

Comment: @GennadiyZolotaryov `bash --version` tells you the version of bash that comes first on your PATH, but it may not be the same version of bash that you're using as a shell. run `echo $BASH_VERSION` to see the latter.

Comment: **Warning for anyone trying this on macOS + Homebrew**: After setting `HISTSIZE=-1` and `HISTFILESIZE=-1` some of my scripts started failing. Took a while to figure out that these scripts were still referencing the builtin `#!/bin/bash` (Bash3) and it was choking on this directive and locking up. I added this check: `[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}" -ge 43 ] || return` to `.bash_profile` and put the bash4+ specific directives below that to allow them to coexist.

Comment: I have bash version `5.0.17`. Using negative values doesn't give me unlimited history, only about 2 months, history file is at 71KB.

Comment: Is there any difference between setting them to empty strings and setting them to -1, other than that the former is works in earlier versions? And if that is the case, when would one ever choose the latter over the former?

Answer (score 602):

After many large, ugly iterations and weird edge cases over the years, I now have a concise section of [my `.bashrc`](https://github.com/fotinakis/bashrc/blob/master/init.sh#L46) dedicated to this.

First, you must comment out or **remove this section of your `.bashrc`** (default for Ubuntu). If you don't, then certain environments (like running `screen` sessions) will still truncate your history:

```
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
# HISTSIZE=1000
# HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

Second, **add this** to the bottom of your .bashrc:

```
# Eternal bash history.
# ---------------------
# Undocumented feature which sets the size to "unlimited".
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "
# Change the file location because certain bash sessions truncate .bash_history file upon close.
# http://superuser.com/questions/575479/bash-history-truncated-to-500-lines-on-each-login
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_eternal_history
# Force prompt to write history after every command.
# http://superuser.com/questions/20900/bash-history-loss
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

**Note:** every command is written immediately after it's run, so if you accidentally paste a password you cannot just "`kill -9 %%`" to avoid the history write, you'll need to remove it manually.

Also note that each bash session will load the full history file in memory, but even if your history file grows to 10MB (which will take a *long, long* time) you won't notice much of an effect on your bash startup time.

Comment: Could I put this setting globally in global bashrc so that it overrides settings for all users ?

Comment: @user01, I think yes, you can, I would only set a limit to a big value. Just to be sure.

Comment: I did all these and my log keeps being capped on 2000 :(, could my version be bugged? any other tips? ubuntu 14.04, bash 4.3.11, HISTFILE=~/.bash_eternal_history, HISTFILESIZE=-1, HISTSIZE=-1, HISTTIMEFORMAT='[%F %T] ' (instead of '-1' I tried the empty option too to no avail..)

Comment: @AquariusPower - Try what is exactly above, make the `HISTFILESIZE=` and `HISTSIZE=` blank instead of -1, and make sure you don't have any other declarations of those params in a .bashrc or .bash_profile or .profile.

Comment: culprit at `.bashrc`, I had that setup after on another file loaded by .bashrc..., now working! thx!

Comment: Add it in my standard bash system, and adding current history is also nice, so after config, run `cat ~/.bash_history >>~/.bash_eternal_history`

Comment: To retain history history, initialize the history file with your current history.

Comment: You say "First, you must comment out or remove this section of your .bashrc (default for Ubuntu). If you don't, then certain environments (like running screen sessions) will still truncate your history:" Why does this only affect envs like screen & not others? I'm running Mint 17, & had to remove those two lines from the /etc/bash.bashrc, otherwise everytime I started a screen session the history file was truncated to 2000 entries. Confusing thing is when I opened a new terminal the /etc/bash.bashrc file was being run then also, but in that case it was not truncating the history file...

Comment: @PaulCaheny I don't actually know why it truncates in those environments but not others, it was very surprising to me when I found that out. Haven't ever tracked down why!

Comment: Great suggestions.  I use `export HISTFILE="/home/$USER/hist/\`uname -n``tty | tr '/' '-'\`"` to keep shell history separate per session (based on hostname and tty name).  Of course I have to create ~/hist directory first.

Comment: @Blauhirn It immediately appends all the unwritten history in memory to the history file, instead of waiting for the end of the shell session.

Comment: Bash truncates the history file during start up so you *must* comment out the default settings in .bashrc. Merely overriding the settings later in your own custom rc file will just leave you with the fruistrating situation where it looks like bash isn't respecting your changes to the history storage configuration.

Comment: It still trims history to 500 lines

Comment: Many thanks - the fact that **setting `HISTFILESIZE` (and possibly `HISTSIZE`) will take _immediate_ effect _cannot_ be overemphasized**.

Comment: Is there a good explanation why you don't need to set `shopt -s histappend`? too?

Comment: @Muzer: This answer probably assumes that the default .bashrc file already includes `shopt -s histappend`. This is true of Ubuntu 18.04.1 Desktop at least, but might not be true on other Linux installations.

Comment: If I put these in my `.bashrc`, is there anything `zsh` does that `bash` won't do?  (same question to other "modern" shells like `fish`)

Comment: Use `HISTSIZE=-1` and `HISTFILESIZE=-1`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make commands entered from another `bash` tab available in the current tab. I use `konsole` if that matters. The `.bash_eternal_history` does contain commands entered from all tabs, but `Ctrl+R` in each tab only recalls commands entered in *it*. I haven't logged out and back in yet since the effect was supposed to be immediate.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheMeillaud: that would initialize `.bash_eternal_history` with `.bash_history` in its typical format, which is one command per line, but this answer sets the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to include the timestamp.

Comment: @fotinakis: can you explain in the answer the advantage of setting the `HISTTIMEFORMAT`? Is that critical for the setup to work, or optional? Are those timestamps displayed in a user-readable form anywhere?

Comment: @DanDascalescu the timestamps prefix each command. they are written to the history file. they are not critical, they history does not write them by default. with the timestamp written before the command, parsing the history may be more complicated (you may need to ignore the timestamp text), but you have some context on when the command was ran

Comment: Important to know that the `~/.bashrc` file also needs to be adjusted - I just added the following snipped to my `.bash_profile` - `sed -i 's/^\(HISTSIZE=.*\)/#\1/' ~/.bashrc && sed -i 's/^\(HISTFILESIZE=.*\)/#\1/' ~/.bashrc` - if you move to another PC or use it in a VM, you don't miss that

Answer (score 58):

As Jörg Beyer [mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9457288/875915), `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` are key.

In addition, you should **definitely** check out the environmental variable `HISTCONTROL`, which lets you do cool things like not store duplicate history commands (`HISTCONTROL=erasedups`). There's no point having unlimited history if you have to browse through hundreds of lines of `cd ..` or similar.

Links: [here](http://ss64.com/bash/history.html), and [working with bash history](http://blog.macromates.com/2008/working-with-history-in-bash/). The bash Variable FAQ is also [worth browsing](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_60.html).

Comment: Those lines of cd give you context for the commands issued.  They're actually incredibly useful.  I can't understand why anyone would ever want to delete them, unless the only way you ever use history is by paging through it one command at a time.

Comment: @simont I also use the ignorespace option with HISTCONTROL then use this for anything I don't want written to history, such as passwords.

Comment: Keeping the lines in order is very useful if you reuse sequences of commands. E.g. `Ctrl-r` somechars `Ctrl-o`  `Ctrl-o`  `Ctrl-o`  `Ctrl-o`. That's why I keep duplicates in history.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon what's `Ctrl-o` for ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă `Ctrl-o` runs the command at prompt and shows right away the command right after the previous one in history. One benefit is that after using `Ctrl-r` to find an old command (possibly using up and down arrow to move to neighboring commands in history), it is enough to keep `Ctrl` pressed and press `o` multiple times to run again a previous series of commands, even in infinite loop if you want. See also [GNU Readline - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline "GNU Readline - Wikipedia")

Comment: @iconoclast I rarely, if ever, use `cd`. But if you do, I can see why it matters to you.

Answer (score 32):

There are (at least) two relevant env vars here:

- HISTSIZE: the number of entries that are **stored in memory**
- HISTFILESIZE: the number of lines tat are **stored in history file**

**details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454838/4632019)

I think that we can agree that the term **unlimited** is often the same as **very big** (or do you have unlimited file storage?). So just set the values very large.

Comment: "It should be noted that 1000000000 is only equal to infinity for very small values of infinity. – sepp2k" lol. yes, i am content with small values of infinity (say, a month of frequent terminal use).

Comment: a month of frequent terminal use is an infititesimally small fraction of infinity.  I would say a lifetime of frequent terminal use equates to a ***very very very*** small value of infinity.  But a lifetime of frequent terminal use is good enough for my shell history.  ;)

Comment: Older versions of zsh at least will crash if you set HISTSIZE and/or HISTFILESIZE too large because it tries to pre-allocate enough memory.  This became relevant when running tools that use zsh as their shell (dbx for example).

Comment: There are different types of infinity: see countably infinite and uncountably infinite.  Inquiring minds might be interested.. and I'm fairly sure there are a lot of those hanging around stackoverflow.