# Preprocess line before it is processed by bash

Tags: bash

Is there a way to preprocess a line entered into bash in interactive mode before it is processed by bash?

I'd like to introduce some custom shorthand syntax to deal with long paths. For example, instead of writing 'cd /one/two/three/four/five', I'd like to be able to write something like 'cd /.../five', and then my preprocessing script would replace this by the former command (if a unique directory 'five' exists somewhere below /).

I found http://glyf.livejournal.com/63106.html which describes how to execute a hook function before a command is executed. However, the approach does not allow to alter the command to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way of doing this generally for all commands.

However, you can do it for specific commands by overriding them with a function. For your `cd` case, you can stick something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
cd() {
  path="$1"
  [[ $path == "/.../five" ]] && path="/one/two/three/four/five"
  builtin cd "$path"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` 4 or later, you can use the `globstar` option.

```
shopt -s globstar
cd /**/five
```

assuming that `five` is a unique directory.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **not directly**. As you have found, the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable allows you to issue a command before the prompt is displayed, which can allow for some very creative uses, e.g. [**Unlimited BASH History**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history), but nothing that would allow you to parse and replace input directly.

What you are wanting to do **can** be accomplished using functions and alias within your `.bashrc`.  One approach would be to use either `findutils-locate` or simply a `find` command to search directories below the present working directory for the last component in the ellipsed path, and then provide the full path in return. However, even with the indexing, `locate` would take a bit of time, and depending on the depth, `find` itself may be to slow for generically doing this for all possible directories. If however, you had a list of specific directories you would like to implement something like this for, then the solution would be workable and relatively easy.

To provide any type of prototype or further detail, we would need to know more about how you intent to use the path information, and whether multiple paths could be provided in a single command.

Another issue arises if the directory `five` is non-unique...