# Save command history in pdb

Tags: python, debugging

Is there a way to save pdb (python debugger) command history across sessions? Also, can I specify history length?

This is similar to the question [How can I make gdb save the command history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176800/how-can-i-make-gdb-save-the-command-history), however for pdb instead of gdb.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you can do this with IPython:

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#history

ipdb replacement for pdb:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb

Comment: Are you sure this can be done with ipdb? I was not able to get my history from my old ipdb sessions.

Comment: IPDB doesn't support the same magic commands as IPython does. Unless you can show me a way to input `%magic-commands` in IPDB, the downvote stays.

Answer (score 20):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852170/how-to-define-a-new-function-in-pdb/35859009#35859009) post.  It is possible to save history in pdb.  By default, pdb does not read multiple lines. So all functions need to be on a single line.

In ~/.pdbrc:

```
import atexit
import os
import readline

historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.pyhistory")

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath): import readline; readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath): readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history, historyPath=historyPath)
```

Comment: Make sure you also remove old entries from this file, it can grow really big ~2GB in my case in just a month.

Comment: [readline.set_history_length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#readline.set_history_length) can be used to truncate history size automatically.

Answer (score 17):

Credits: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PdbRcIdea

pdb uses readline so we can instruct readline to save history:

`.pdbrc`

```py
# NB: `pdb` only accepts single-line statements
import os
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.pdbrc.py")) as _f: _f = _f.read()
exec(_f)
del _f
```

`.pdbrc.py`

```py
def _pdbrc_init():
    # Save history across sessions
    import readline
    histfile = ".pdb-pyhist"
    try:
        readline.read_history_file(histfile)
    except IOError:
        pass
    import atexit
    atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, histfile)
    readline.set_history_length(500)

_pdbrc_init()
del _pdbrc_init
```

---

For the drop-in replacement [`pdb++`](https://github.com/pdbpp/pdbpp), copy the above function code into the `setup()` method:

```py
from pdb import DefaultConfig, Pdb


class Config(DefaultConfig):
    def setup(self, pdb):
        ## Save history across sessions
        #
        import readline
        ...
```

Comment: This works beautifully for the `pdbpp / pdb++` debugger. Thanks!

Comment: To put the history file in your home dir, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65924715/456550).

Comment: This was helpful, but I noticed that the .pdbrc file is read _every time the debugger breaks in_. That means every time you run `continue` it'll reload the file. the atexit handler only runs when the whole program exits. So this stomps on updates to your session's history. I ended up using a hack with NameError to only execute the initialization once.

Comment: Still working, Ubuntu 23.04, Python 3.10.7. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

An example for clearing / reading / printing the current pdb history:

```
(Pdb) readline.clear_history()
(Pdb) print('hello pdb')
hello pdb
(Pdb) from pprint import pprint; import readline
(Pdb) y = range(readline.get_current_history_length() + 2)
(Pdb) print([readline.get_history_item(x) for x in y])
```

output:

```
[None, 
"print('hello pdb')", 
'from pprint import pprint; import readline', 
'y = range(readline.get_current_history_length() + 2)',
'print([readline.get_history_item(x) for x in y])']
```

reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html

two liner without `readline.clear_history` for what has been input to pdb so far:

```
from pprint import pprint; import readline
pprint([readline.get_history_item(x) for x in range(readline.get_current_history_length() + 1)])
```

Comment: This is a useful example of how to access and delete the history recorded by the readline library.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @olejorgenb's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390866/456550), I wanted the history file in my home directory rather than in the current directory, so I used `pathlib.Path.expanduser`.

```
import pdb

class Config(pdb.DefaultConfig):

    def setup(self, pdb):
        # Save history across sessions
        import readline
        from pathlib import Path
        histfile_path = Path("~/.pdb-pyhist").expanduser()

        try:
            readline.read_history_file(histfile_path)
        except IOError:
            pass

        import atexit
        atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, histfile_path)
        readline.set_history_length(500)
```

This is my setup for configuring `pdbpp` (an improved debugger, aka `pdb++`,  https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/). You can use the same idea along with @olejorgenb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390866/456550) to configure regular `pdb`.

Comment: Shouldn't you use a `super().setup(pdb)` as the first line of the `setup` function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way with "stock" pdb. But I wrote a replacement debugger that does that.

just install Pycopia from source: http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/checkout and it's in pycopia.debugger.