# How to define a new function in pdb

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

Why can't I define new functions when I run `pdb`?

For example take myscript.py:

```
#!/gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/python
print "Hello World"
print "I see you"
```

If I run `python -m pdb myscript.py` and try to interactively define a new function:

```
def foo():
```

I get the error:

```
*** SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<stdin>, line 1)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Use `ipdb` instead for multiline support

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define your function in a one line statement using `;` instead of indentation, like this:

```
(Pdb) def foo(): print 'Hello world'; print 'I see you'
(Pdb) foo()
Hello world
I see you
```

Answer (score 27):

I don't think it supports multi-line input.  You can workaround by spawning up an interactive session from within pdb.  Once you are done in the interactive session, exit it with Ctrl+D.

```
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) !import code; code.interact(local=vars())
(InteractiveConsole)
In : def foo():
...:     print('hello in pdb')
...: 
In : # use ctrl+d here to return to pdb shell...
(Pdb) foo()
hello in pdb
```

Comment: Since Python 3.2, there's the pdb builtin command `interact` that does this. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-interact

Comment: @KFL Thanks for the comment, but how would you make a function defined in there remain visible after exiting interaction?  The InteractiveConsole spawned by pdb builtin `interact` does seems to contain names from the outer scope, but any functions defined within don't seem to be usable after exiting the interaction.

Answer (score 2):

i was able to import python modules from the `pdb` command line.

if you can import python modules, then you should be able to define your functions in a file and just do an import of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If your application happens to have IPython as a dependency, you could drop yourself into a feature-rich IPython REPL right from ipdb:

```
import IPython; IPython.embed()
```

From inside, if you run IPython's magic command `whos`, you should see all the locally defined variables in the current `pdb` frame.