# GDB - unable to get command history working

Tags: gdb, command, history

I'm new to GDB and can't get the command history (auto complete/up arrow to old commands working).

At my root I have a .gbd_init file (and I also have an identical file in my working directory):

```
set history save

set history filename ~/.gbd_history

set history on

set history expansion on
```

I also have an empty .gbd_history file at my root.

In GBD 'show history' gives:

```
(gdb) show history

expansion:  History expansion on command input is on.

filename:  The filename in which to record the command history is      
"/home/jenny/C_Programs/CS575_Algorithms/HW3/Problem1/.gdb_history".

save:  Saving of the history record on exit is on.

size:  The size of the command history is unlimited.

(gdb)
```

But the GBD command 'show commands' yields nothing and the up-arrows and tab don't do anything.

The .gbd_history file exists but is empty.

```
 jenny@jennys-virtual-machine ~/C_Programs/CS575_Algorithms/HW3/Problem1 $ ls -ls .gbd*

 0 -rwxrwxrwx 1 jenny jenny  0 Oct  1 22:16 .gbd_history

 4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 jenny jenny 94 Oct  1 22:01 .gbdinit
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.  Typing in each command is getting old fast.

Jenny

Answer (score 1):

> At my root I have a .gbd_init file (and I also have an identical file
>   in my working directory):

You have misspelled gdb init file name. It should be named `.gdbinit`. `.gbd_init` is not get executed by gdb and history saving is not turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Your .gdbinit script obviously is not executed, as you can see from your gdb_history filename, which has it's default value (gdb_history in *current* directory).

Try executing this init script in your current directory with gdb -x .gdbinit, as it may be disabled by default. At least my gdb wants me to set some kind of auto-load safe-path before it will allow loading of init scripts residing outside of home directory. See details [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto_002dloading-safe-path.html).

If you are looking to use history only to not have to repeat commands, you should probably just write a script with all those commands, and execute it with gdb -x script etc.

And surely check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176800/how-can-i-make-gdb-save-the-command-history) on how to enable command history easily.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It's working now.

I updated my .gdbinit file to begin with "set auto-load safe-path /" 
and then invoked gdb with 
"gdb -q -iex "set auto-load safe-path /home/jenny" program -tui" 
and now the command history/up arrow is working.