# execute multiple gdb commands in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, gdb

If there is a way to do this natively in gdb, something like 'load script', then feel free to ignore the emacs part of this question.

I frequently wind up doing the following in a pretty high-count loop:

1. start gdb (in emacs if that helps).
2. set several breakpoints (same breakpoints every time).  Usually have to enter "y" I want to make breakpoint pending on future shared library load.
3. set some watchpoints (same watchpoints)
4. debug for a while.
5. close gdb.
6. goto 1.

So it would make my life much easier if I could save the commands to write to a buffer or file, and load and execute that set of commands every time I start gdb.  Bonus points if I don't have to enter "y" to confirm that gdb should make the breakpoints pending on future library load.

What would be super awesom is if I could save all current breakpoints (by name not by address as those might change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all your commands in a file and invoke gdb with the arguments `-x /path/to/file`. The answers to any questions will be defaulted to something safe...

```
$ cat init.gdb
break write

$ gdb -q -x init.gdb a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
Function "write" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N;
    input not from terminal]
(gdb)
```

But in this case, you want the answer to be `y`. There's often a gdb variable that can be set to override the default choice. Here, it's `set breakpoint pending on`.

```
$ cat init2.gdb
set breakpoint pending on
break write

$ gdb -q -x init2.gdb a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
Function "write" not defined.
Breakpoint 1 (write) pending.
(gdb)
```

To save breakpoints, use the `save breakpoints` command.

```
(gdb) save breakpoints bp.gdb
Saved to file 'bp.gdb'.
(gdb) quit
$ cat bp.gdb
break write
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems very helpful.  Playing with it now.

Answer (score 1):

Well i think you can save command history by `set history save`

The correct explanation for the same type of question is given in below link

[How can I make gdb save the command history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176800/how-can-i-make-gdb-save-the-command-history)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, gdb will automatically load a script file.  Exactly which file is loaded depends on gdb version, but in older ones it reads .gdbinit in the current directory; and in newer ones will read "$EXE-gdb.gdb", where $EXE is the name of the program you're debugging.  See the manual for all the details.