# Changing the default main file in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

When I run gdb, there seems to be a notion of a main file, as if I set a breakpoint with just a number, it will get set for the source file that contains the **main** function.

How can I reconfigure `gdb` to set this to the file containing a function named `my_main`? (My actual `main` is provided by my library, in 99.9% of cases I want to focus on the the wrapped and prefixed main that the actual, library-provided, `main` calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB isn't doing what you say.  When you say `break LINE` it sets a breakpoint in the "current" file, as per the docs:

> The current source file is the last file whose source text was printed.

So perhaps what you want is to always set a breakpoint in `my_main`.  If it helps you can make GDB let you up-arrow or Ctrl-R search backward through commands entered in previous sessions by following the instructions here: [How can I make gdb save the command history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176800/how-can-i-make-gdb-save-the-command-history)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a breakpoint using directly function name: `break my_main` or you can specify filename and line: `break file.c:100`